# error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-build

I'm trying to take the iOS build of a Flutter project. No matter what I try it just gives me the following error:

> **error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/GoogleService-Info.plist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')**

This is the set of commands I am trying to get the build with:

- flutter pub get
- flutter clean
- flutter build ios (this gives the above error)

Here is my flutter doctor output

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.16.3-pre.67, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[!] Connected device

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

The `flutter build ios --verbose` ends with following error:

```
Encountered error while building for the device.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
#1      BuildIOSCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:93:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:722:18)
#3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1155:38)
#4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1048:19)
#5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:141:18)
#6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:682:45)
#7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:711:32)
#8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:526:5)
#9      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:556:7)
#10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1147:13)
#11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1040:19)
#12     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:942:7)
#13     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:982:23)
#14     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#15     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#16     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#17     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Here is the image of the folder structure. As you can see, there is no 'Users' folder that holds the Google plist. So, it is quite confusing why would the script try to copy the plist from a non-existing directory. Any advice to fix this would be highly appreciated. TIA :-)

[image]

Comment: Remove it and then again try adding the file into the directory from Xcode, then choose copy items if needed and add to target checkmark. Is there GoogleService-Info.plist file inside the Runner directory ? (See it from Finder app)

Comment: Ah! I did remove and add back via VSCode. Didn't try with Xcode. Seems to be working. I will confirm when the execution is over.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Remove the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and then again add the file into the `Runner` directory using Xcode, then choose `copy items if needed` and `add to target` checkmark. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: still GoogleService-Info.plist file not found

Comment: this answer is helpful but must be combined with the answer from @Paresh Mangukiya provided below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Best way to resolve such a problem (Even if the GoogleService-info.plist is within the runner folder).

1. In Android Studio, drag the file GoogleService-info.plist from ios/Runner folder to the desktop or anywhere on the disk. (If it presents)
2. Now go to Xcode again, delete the reference of GoogleService-info.plist file from the project, Then from File> Add Files to Runner and select the backup copy of GoogleService-info.plist as per the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Only Solution that worked for me was dragging the file directly into the runner folder in xcode. Very important to move it into the runner folder not the runner itself.]

Only Solution that worked for me was dragging the file directly into the runner folder in xcode. Very important to move it into the runner folder not the runner itself.